# Ninject binding with two generic parameters in types

Tags: c#, generics, ninject

I have this interface:

```
public interface IRepository<TDomain, TBusiness>
    where TDomain : class
    where TBusiness : class
    {...}
```

And this class:

```
public class Repository<TDomain, TBusiness> : IRepository<TDomain,    TBusiness>
    where TDomain : class
    where TBusiness : class
    {...}
```

And when i bind in with ninject, something like:

```
Kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>))
      .To(typeof(Repository<>))
      .InRequestScope();
```

And have an error "Incorrect number of type parameters in ...".
When I have only one generic in type everything works fine.
Have anyone solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Ninject, the error you are getting is a C# compiler error. That's because the correct way to specify a type with two generic arguments is the following:

```
typeof(IRepository<,>)
```

Comment: Thank's! Don't know about this syntax!